# Can I use MySql CASE in this way?

Tags: mysql, case

There is much more code but I am trying to stay within the guidelines of my work rules.

I am trying to use a CASE statement like this:

```
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS
    SELECT DISTINCT IM.EDPNO
  , IM.ITEMNO
  , IM.DESCRIPTION
  , SUBSTRING(EX.REFITEMNO,6,20) AS UPC_CODE
  , IM.VENDORNO
  , CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_DETAIL_URL,RTRIM(IM.ITEMNO))  AS URL

  SELECT CASE DIVISION WHEN 'C4' OR 'J3' THEN
    ,CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg')
  End AS IMAGE_URL;
```

Then I imagine I would follow it up with another Select Case where I would get the image from a Lookup table instead on concating.

Comment: When you run the query does it generate the result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  , CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_DETAIL_URL,RTRIM(IM.ITEMNO))  AS URL
 SELECT CASE DIVISION WHEN 'C4' OR 'J3' THEN
    ,CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg')
  End AS IMAGE_URL
```

needs to be

```
  , CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_DETAIL_URL,RTRIM(IM.ITEMNO))  AS URL
, CASE WHEN DIVISION IN ('C4', 'J3') THEN 
 CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg') END AS IMAGE_URL
```

You are missing a comma after `URL`, shouldn't have the leading `SELECT` as it is already in a `SELECT` statement and you can't have the `OR` when using the simple form of the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
SELECT CASE DIVISION WHEN 'C4' OR 'J3' THEN
    CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg')
  End AS IMAGE_URL
```